# Is there a way to implement a circular pane in Javafx?

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, pane

I am trying to redesign a 1980s game called 'The Defenders', in the game the pane is translatable and follows the spaceship. As soon as the space ship reaches one end of the pane, it automatically warps to the other end making the spaceship go in a circular loop. Is there any way I can implement something of that sort in Java Fx, I can just relocate the ship back to the other end but I would have to do that for all the objects. Is there another way to do this? Thank you

Comment: If you implement this the right way you only need to implement this logic in a single place even though it applies to multiple nodes...

Comment: Your question is too broad. Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.